# How do I set the transparency in Image3D?

Tags: image3d, opacity

I have an Image3D plot, I like the color palette, but I don't like that for zero values the blocks are simply transparent (I would like them faint, but visible). 
How do I change the transparency setting?

I could do it manually by right clicking on every graph, edit the color function and draw my custom curve. But is there instead an option in the Image3D command?

Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to check the ColorFunction option here: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Image3D.html (and *not* here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you are looking for is `ColorFunction`.  When you create a colour function manually using the GUI, you can press the Copy Function button at the bottom. Paste the function into the notebook, and store it in a variable named `cfun`.  Then use `Image3D[yourDataOrYourImage, ColorFunction -> cfun]`.

Be sure to look up the `ColorFunction` option within the [`Image3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Image3D.html) documentation page.  There are many examples, including a number of pre-set named colour functions that are not available in 2D.